# Benefit of storing a data as an index rather than just Date

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Why do I see "index = True" whenever creating a table with a date? What is the benefit of storing a data as an index rather than just Date?

```
class Puppy(Base):
"""Connects to the Puppy table
"""
    __tablename__ = 'puppy'

    puppy_id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = Column(String(10), nullable = False)
    picture = Column(String)
    dateOfbirth = Column(Date, index = True)
    breed = Column(String(80), nullable = False)
    gender = Column(String(6), nullable = False)
    weight = Column(Integer, nullable = False)
    shelter_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('shelter.shelter_id'))
    shelter = relationship(Shelter)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little background.

An SQL index isn't a special storage type for the individual bits of data, so much as an optimized storage type for the set of data.  Its telling the database to keep an copy of that column, or groups of columns, that is stored in a presorted format, optimized for that particular datatype.  Indexes are *generally* placed on columns you expect to do a lot of searching (where clauses) or joining on, in order to speed up those operations.

This has a lot of benefits beyond the obvious, for example the DBMS can do all evaluation with preoptimized data, and can do it all without ever having to read the full table from the disk, which can be very expensive.  After it figures out what it needs, it then only has to access the subset of rows on the disk that met the query conditions by using pointers to the complete row, stored in the index.

In the case that only indexed data was requested from the table, many DBMS' will take it a step further and never pull the actual table from the disk, just pulling the data from the indexes.

So the reason dates are often indexed often has more to do with how datetime data is used in the human experience.  It's a common select condition ("give me all the sales for last week"), a common join condition ("compare this month's sales to last month"), and a piece of data often needed to answer questions that don't need additional metadata ("what day did the customer make that purchase?")

Additionally its worth noting that whatever format the database returns datetime data to you in (2015-10-23 12:34:56), most times its internally its storing it as either an integer (seconds since 1970) or as a fixed precision decimal (if it has microseconds for example), and just converting it when returning it to you.  Integers and fixed decimals are really easy (computationally) to index, sort, join and otherwise manipulate compared to other datatypes.

Thats why integers are the default choice for a primary key absent a strong reason not to, and datetimes are just a one time calculation off from integers, which when the db might be performing a billion operations between the time it converts the datetime in a query to an int, and converting it back when it returns the data, really isn't expensive at all.  So you've got a datatype that indexes really well that additionally has a lot of meaning to the human using the data, compared a random integer.